# Android Custom Notification layout

Tags: android

i want to design a custom notification view with `BigPictureStyle` by not using xml, i want to totally design my remote view using java code(directly using layouts(most LL or RL) and widgets(`imageview` , `textview`)). Using xml it was easy, but when i use the pure java code to design my remote view , my app crashes.

```
    RemoteViews contentView = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),R.id.custom_notification);
```

In the above codeline instead of passing the layout resource(R.id.custom_notification), i want to pass a relative layout java code object id(it has the some child view's inside).

```
 RemoteViews contentView = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),mainLayout.getId());
```

This above statement thorws following error.

```
android - Bad notification posted - Couldn't expand RemoteViews for: StatusBarNotification
```

please help.

Comment: You can't do that. The layout you pass the `RemoteViews` is inflated in a remote process. That is, those `View`s are created there, local to that process. You can't create `View`s in your process, and pass them to another.

Comment: Thanks Mike M for your reply, Do we have any workarounds/alternative/ any patches related to this issue.

Comment: Well, the only thing that comes to mind off the bat would be to go ahead and inflate your layout off-screen (i.e., don't add it to an `Activity`), set it up as needed, force it to measure out appropriately, then draw it to a `Bitmap` that you could place on a regular `RemoteViews`, possibly one that's just a big `ImageView`.

Comment: Ok thanks Mike M, Ill try it out.

Answer (score -2):

Plz check this code.I implement this feature in my application.

```
        Intent notificationIntent = null;
        notificationIntent = new Intent(this, Screen_splash.class);

        NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle bigPictureStyle = new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle();
        bigPictureStyle.bigPicture(getBitmapFromURL(img_url));
        bigPictureStyle.setSummaryText(message);

        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) this
                .getSystemService(this.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
        builder.setContentTitle("ToothApp");
        builder.setContentText(message)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo_noti)
                .setStyle(bigPictureStyle)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentIntent(
                        PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 10,
                                notificationIntent, 0));

        Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager
                .getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        builder.setSound(alarmSound);

        mNotificationManager.notify(1, builder.build());
```

Thanks

Comment: Prosanto, Thanks for the replay, but this code is the native style , which already worked for me, My main motive for this custom notification is to show bitmap which is already working for me as i tested it, and i want to show gif images, small video clips, carousal type views in notification view.